# Localized error in swift (translation)

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, localization, nserror

I have multiple localization in my app. When error occurred the app sends it to backend and shows to user. I want to send non-localized error message to backend. Is there any way to achieve this?

EDIT: Error message is for example internet connection problem, so it isn't localised message, but it's translated.

Comment: When error occurred the app sends it to backend and shows to user - does the app send localised message to backend ?

Comment: please share your code to check

Comment: You can send message and language code means "en" or "ar" based on that backend show error in that localiuzed language

Comment: @Nitish nope, error messages aren't localized, for example it is internet connection error.

Answer (score -1):

A really simple solution would be something like:

```
let errorForBackend = "Wystąpił błąd"
let errorForUser = NSLocalizedString("Wystąpił błąd", comment: "An Error Occurred message")

sendErrorToBackend(errorForBackend)
displayAlert(errorForUser)
```

Comment: Error messages are not localized, but they are translated. This is for example Internet connection error.